# Printing Excel to PDF has cells on new pages, while they look fine in Preview

Tags: excel, pdf, printing

I'm using ExportAsFixedFormat to create a PDF of a multi-page workbook. In Print Preview these look fine and everything "prints" fine.

However, when I export to PDF, the right-most column is cut off, and appears on a second page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install the free Bullzip PDF printer.  http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php  Far more flexible and higher quality than publishing to PDF within Office.